# -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, selector

I am very new to Swift as I justed started on it only a few months back. I have an aching problem with this error.

```
-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance XXX
```

Here is a list of possible fixes that I have so far gathered and implemented already.

1. I have changed the Custom Class to `CheckboxQuestion` class instead of the `UIViewController` class.

[Custom Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCxDC.png)

2. I have connected the tableview to the datasource and delegate.
3. I have accounted for all loose referencing outlets.
4. I have named the reusable identifier outlet for each prototype cell.

[prototype cell 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz3Q2.png)

After all those, I am still getting the error above.

The breakpoint of the exception error happened in the appdelegate class at this line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Is there something else which I am missing?

Here is the code for CheckboxQuestion Class code

```
import UIKit

var checkboxCellInfo = ["Field 1", "Field 2"]

class CheckboxQuestion: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//1. determine number of rows of cells to show data
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  
    return checkboxCellInfo.count + 1
}

//2. inputs info into each cell from array 'cellInfo'
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {

    if indexPath.row <= checkboxCellInfo.count - 1 {

        let cell:CheckboxQuestionCellConnect = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CheckboxNumber") as! CheckboxQuestionCellConnect

        return cell 

     } else {

        let cell:CheckboxQuestionCellConnect = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CheckboxAdd") as! CheckboxQuestionCellConnect

        return cell

    }  
}

//3. determines height of each cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please ensure you deleted outlets from code but not from storyboard.just right click on tableview from storyboard .delete outlets and reconnect it.May be you have added two outlets for same tableview.

Comment: Hi Devendra. Followed your advise and realised it was a silly mistake of mine. I had another viewcontroller (RadioButtonQuestion) of the same structure as I described above. I carelessly connected its tableview to the datasource and delegate to the viewcontroller in the storyboard first. The reason it gave the error was because I did not even create a RadioButtonQuestion class to accomodate for it! So the error isn't coming from the original CheckboxQuestion class, but from the missing RadioButtonQuestion class. Will learn from this painful lesson. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have added below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
      ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
```

And also connected the `delegate` and `datasource` to `tableview` in stoaryboard.

Answer (score 3):

You're implementing `UITableViewDelegate`/`UITableViewDataSource` methods, but it doesn't seem like your class conforms to either of them. Since you're inheriting from `UIViewController`, you'll need to add those protocols and set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table view to `self`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

If the view controller only shows a view controller, you should consider using a `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`, then the stuff above doesn't apply - you get that for free with a `UITableViewController`. But I can't tell from code if this is the case.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I have added the UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource classes as follows

Comment: `class CheckboxQuestion: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {`. How do I set them to self?

Comment: Are you using a custom layout with the table view or just full screen table view? If it's full screen you should go for the `UITableViewController`, which does all this for you. I will add in how to set the delegate and datasource in my answer.

Comment: I am using a custom layout. There is a Text View and the Table View inside a Container View.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you may have forget to assign tableview delegate and datasource to self.

self.tableView.dataSource   = self

self.tableView.delegate     = self

Comment: Tried that. Still not successful.

Comment: @kiwidude89 are u using same class name for both the table view cells..Have u taken any outlet it cell class.. can you  show your cell class

Comment: yes I am using the same class. This is the code. `import UIKit

class CheckboxQuestionCellConnect: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var orangeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }`

}

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed UITableView protocol implementation, **Make sure you implemented the protocols** you're required to implement.

1. UITableViewDelegate
2. UITableViewDataSource

add protocols implementations on h file:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

add required methods on m file:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had provided:
1. all the outlets right,
2. datasource and delegate right,

The thing i was missing was:
I hadn't provided the class and storyboard identifier for UIViewController in the storyboard. hence it shows

-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

because a normal UIViewController does not have these methods, when we conform to UITableViewDatasource, we provide it in our custom UIViewController class.

So please check the identity inspector for UIViewController in the storyboard and provide the proper class there.

Consider the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have this in your controller.

`extension NameController: UITableViewDelegate { // code... }`

`extension NameController: UITableViewDataSource { // code... }`

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you add a same class name in different viewcontroller. one of these viewcontroller have a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are not connected your file with the storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I have not connected the ViewController in storyboard to my custom class