# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f821c419e00'

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error when I click in my view.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[QRCodeReader.FoodsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f821c419e00'

Here's my code
I am trying to put the first chunk of information (name) in the table. The view doesn't load and crashes.

```
struct Foods {
    var name : String
    var expiryDay : String
    var expiryMonth : String
    var expiryYear : String
    var calories : String
    var sugar : String
    var fat : String
    var salt : String
    var sodium : String
    var allergyEffects : String
}

class FoodsViewController: QRCodeViewController {
    @IBOutlet var foodDisplay: UITableView!

    var food = [Foods(name: "Marco Chocolate", expiryDay: "15", expiryMonth: "1", expiryYear: "2020", calories: "2000", sugar: "20", fat: "30", salt: "10", sodium: "5", allergyEffects: "Cocoa Products")]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return(food.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        let currentLastItem = food[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentLastItem.name
        return cell
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you remove the public keyword , if not works upload a demo link ?

Comment: Are you sure that IBOutlets, data source and delegates are connected to the view controller correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692160/uiviewcontroller-tableviewnumberofrowsinsection-unrecognized-selector-sent/34696231 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431013/tableviewnumberofrowsinsection-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance

Comment: You have to adopt `UITableViewDataSource` and set the delegate somewhere(either in Interface Builder or in code)

Comment: thank you all, problem solved.